# Type of a result after map

Tags: scala, dictionary

I have the followeing classes:

```
case class RolepermissionRow(roleid: Int, permissionid: Int)
```

and

```
case class RolePermissionJSON(
                           var id: Option[Long],
                           var num: Option[Int],
                           var name: Option[String],
                           var perms: Map[String, Boolean])
```

I create a map:

```
var s = Map("1" -> true)
```

I create a RolePermissionJSON:

```
val f = RolePermissionJSON(Some(0), Some(0), Some('test'), s)
```

And I would like to convert the perms Map to RolepermissionRow using the following code:

```
scala> f.perms.map { case (key, value) => if (value) RolepermissionRow(key.toInt, 1) }.toSeq
res7: Seq[Any] = List(RolepermissionRow(1,1))
```

The result is `Seq[Any]` but I would like to have `Seq[RolepermissionRow]`

Comment: What's the `else` case of your conditional statement supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple changes required:

```
val z = f.perms.map { case (key, value) if (value) => RolepermissionRow(key.toInt, 1) }.toSeq
```

Now description:

In your code resulted `Seq` contains of `RolepermissionRow`s if `value` is `true` and `Unit`s otherwise.
You should filter out "empty" elements of map that gives you `Unit`.

UPD: 
@nafg advice to use `collect` to prevent match error in runtime.

Comment: so the problem was that I forgot the `=>` ? Thanks mate.

Comment: This will throw a runtime error when value is false. Use `collect` instead of `map`. Also you don't need `()` around `value` in a guard

Comment: you can write `if value` without `()`

Answer (score 1):

```
f.perms.filter(_._2).map{case (key, value) => RolepermissionRow(key.toInt, 1) }.toSeq
```

I think you should use `filter` firstly to filter the map avoid empty `Map`.

Comment: since you don't use value you can write `case (key, _)`